# Android Firebase Realtime Database orderByChild is not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rating

I'm trying to sort the restaurants by the average rating with orderByChild() but instead of returning them by sorting them by average rating it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
public void filterQuality(){

    DatabaseReference mRatingDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query topQualityQuery = mRatingDb.orderByChild("Average");
    topQualityQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map <String, Double> topQualityMap = new HashMap<>();
            List list = new ArrayList();
            List list2 = new ArrayList();  

            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                topQualityMap.put(ds.getKey(), ds.child("Quality").child("Average").getValue(double.class));
                list.add(ds.child("Quality").child("Average").getValue(double.class));
                list2.add(ds.getKey());

                Log.d("Top Quality", "Value" + topQualityMap);
                Log.d("Top Quality", "Value" + list);
                Log.d("Top Quality", "Value" + list2);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

This is what I get from maps and lists from what I tried to debug:

Value [3.0]

Value [Jurys Inn Newcastle]

Value {Malmaison Newcastle=2.0, Jurys Inn Newcastle=3.0}

D/Top Quality: Value [3.0, 2.0]

D/Top Quality: Value [Jurys Inn Newcastle, Malmaison Newcastle]

D/Top Quality: Value {Malmaison Newcastle=2.0, Jurys Inn Newcastle=3.0, The County Hotel, Newcastle=4.0}

Value [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]

Value [Jurys Inn Newcastle, Malmaison Newcastle, The County Hotel, Newcastle]

Here is my firebase:

[image: Firebase]
[image: Check my update Firebase]

If someone knows why this is not working properly please help.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use orderByChild under two nodes.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Firebase Realtime Database queries can only have one **dynamic** level, but in this JSON that is the case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen good to learn that.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Thanks for your reply. Can you check on my post the update Firebase I have edited? It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the full path to the value you want to order on.

So:

```
DatabaseReference mRatingDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query topQualityQuery = mRatingDb.orderByChild("Quality/Average");
topQualityQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("Firebase", ds.getKey()+": "+ ds.child("Quality/Average").getValue(double.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // NEVER ignore errors
    } 
});
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it is not working. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "it is not working" is unfortunately not very actionable. This is without any doubt one of the things you need to change about your code for it to work. I added some more code to show how to access the data after that.

Comment: This is because I have tried this so many times and I'm not sure what is going wrong. The code you have provided is same with mine.

Comment: You order on `mRatingDb.orderByChild("Average")`, I do `mRatingDb.orderByChild("Quality/Average")`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works but how can I do it in descending order so I can get the highest rating?